# Reading application stdout data using node.js

Tags: node.js

Let's take e.g. "top" application which displays system information and periodically updates it.

I want to run it using node.js and display that information (and updates!). 
Code I've come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var top = spawn('top', []);

top.stdout.on('readable', function () {
    console.log("readable");
    console.log('stdout: '+top.stdout.read());
});
```

It doesn't behave the way I expected. In fact it produces nothing:

```
readable
stdout: null
readable
stdout:
readable
stdout: null
```

And then exits (that is also unexpected).

top application is taken just as an example. Goal is to proxy those updates through the node and display them on the screen (so same way as running top directly from command line).

My initial goal was to write script to send file using scp. Done that and then noticed that I am missing progress information which scp itself displays. Looked around at scp node modules and they also do not proxy it. So backtracked to common application like top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top` is an interactive console program designed to be run against a live pseudo-terminal.

As to your `stdout` reads, `top` is seeing that its `stdin` is not a tty and exiting with an error, thus no output on `stdout`. You can see this happen in the shell if you do `echo | top` it will exit because stdin will not be a tty.

Even if it was actually running though, it's output data is going to contain control characters for manipulating a fixed-dimension console. (like "move the cursor to the beginning of line 2"). It is an interactive user interface and a poor choice as a programmatic data source. "Screen scraping" and interpreting this data and extracting meaningful information is going to be quite difficult and fragile. Have you considered a cleaner approach such as getting the data you need out of the `/proc/meminfo` file and other special files the kernel exposes for this purpose? Ultimately `top` is getting all this data from readily-available special files and system calls, so you should be able to tap into data sources that are convenient for programmatic access instead of trying to screen scrape top.

Now of course, `top` has analytics code to do averages and so forth that you may have to re-implement, so both screen-scraping and going through clean data sources have pros and cons, and aspects that are easy and difficult. But my $0.02 would be focus on good data sources instead of trying to screen scrape a console UI.

Other options/resources to consider:

- The `free` command such as `free -m`
- `vmstat`
- and other commands [described in this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/)
- the [expect program](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is designed to help automate console programs that expect a terminal

And just to be clear, yes it is certainly possible to run `top` as a child process, trick it into thinking there's a tty and all the associated environment settings, and get at the data it is writing. It's just extremely complicated and is analogous to trying to get the weather by taking a photo of the weather channel on a TV screen and running optical character recognition on it. Points for style, but there are easier ways. Look into the `expect` command if you need to research more about tricking console programs into running as subprocesses.

Comment: top was just an example. There are other applications which show progress of execution, etc. And I want to proxy that data through the node to the screen or file if it is possible.

Comment: Updated to explain that top is exiting because stdin is not a tty.

Comment: Peter, and how does top or similar applications show their data, they indeed are not pushing it as stdout?

Comment: When you run `top` interactively in a shell, it's `stdout` data stream is your shell's tty (pseudo-terminal), so it DOES write data to `stdout`, but when you run it via child_process.spawn in node, `top` sees that `stdout` is NOT a tty and just exits. It requires a tty as well as other things such as a TERM environment variable before it will start behaving as normal.